# Create a Shopping Cart Rule - To offer 5% discount for two products or more

Tags: cart, rules

I am trying to create shopping cart rule:

- Two or more DIFFERENT products should be added to a cart
- Include Products only from categories "6 & 8"
- Apply 5% discount

[image: This rule works even if you have one product with QTY >=2, But I need to apply discount only if two different products present in cart]

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is your exact problem? The rule is not used? What did you enter in the other fields?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I think the OP wants the rule to apply only when there are two different skus in the cart - not two of the same sku, which is what will happen in the current incarnation.

Comment: The below answer is a working solution. Please mark it as accepted if it was your answer - otherwise, please enter your own answer and mark as accepted.

Comment: i need one promotion offer solution.
if i am add 1 particular brand 3 items add then i want to special price for this 3 item so how to define there magento.and if i add one more item in cart then 4 th item price is original price. example: buy 3 for $4.99

Answer (score 3):

There aren't many ways to promote product diversity - they have to be set up for specific category pairings. If you have a limited number of categories you may be able to set up enough combinations to apply to a good portion of your catalog.

See this example:

**Set up multiple rules**

- In rule 1, set Product Attribute Combination so that it applies to 1 or more items that are in category 6 but not in 8
- In rule 2, set Product Attribute Combination so that it applies to 1 or more items in category 8, but not in category 6

It will look something like this:

[image: Product diversity rule]

Comment: Thanks Philip! Although my problem was different, this technique helped me resolve it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for us. It will apply 5% discount automatically if 2 or more products added to shopping cart.[image]

[image]