# How to set a rule for buying two products together to reduce the total price?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog-price-rules, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to make a block which shows two products in it with a rule that if a customer bought these two products together the total amount will be reduce by some extent.

e.g. if product A is of $100 and B is of $75, then both will be buy together for $150.

Can anyone has an idea how to apply these kind of promotion rules in magento. I really need to do this as the client need this kind of functionality on its product view page.

[image]

I want something like this.

Comment: Did you think about using group products or bundles?

Comment: Actually i am using configurable products

Comment: You mean the products you want to sell together are already configurable products?

Comment: No no I am not selling the configurable products. I am selling the simple products inside the configurable one.

Comment: Selling two products is in magento achievable through bundle or group products, did you have a look on them?

Comment: yes after your first comment I looked into that, and now I am gonna try that. Thanks @Fabian

Comment: I tried the bundle products and it will adding the two products together, Thanks for this approach but it didn't show the way i want it. as the image above added.

Comment: i get the products as shown in the image above, but now I had a problem when i click on add both to the cart then only one item is added in the cart.
can you tell me how can I add both the products simultaneously. I have the details of the products.

Comment: @Waseem so use your code for the display and add to cart, maybe we can help

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple products to the cart from the same request you need to use the `related_product` url parameter. Simply add the extra products to the end of your add to cart url separated by a coman

```
/product/159/related_product/162,161,160
```

If you are calling the getUrl function to build your url you can do this as follows:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('checkout/cart/add/', array('product'=> 12, 'related_product' => implode(',', array(123,456))));
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done by configurable products.
You will need to find another alternate on this. Because when we add any configurable product the associated products are in "Not visible Individually" Mode.

You can use the following url as an answer, it can be an alternate to your situation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104543/adding-only-the-base-product-into-cart-of-a-bundled-product-in-magento/21255974#21255974

Answer (score 0):

You can view following url::

[Create a Shopping Cart Rule - To offer 5% discount for two products or more](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3047/create-a-shopping-cart-rule-to-offer-5-discount-for-two-products-or-more)

If it is for products from specific category, the this can be used.

Comment: all of my products are from the same category, and I am unable to this kind of functionality to show on the product page with the price rules. I dont know what to do.
Now I am trying a new approach by creating a custom module for this but I am a newbie in magento so cant say how far I can go with the module creation. If you have anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Colleague of mine remembered the extension that can do this: [WizKunde Configurable Bundle](http://shop.wizkunde.nl/configurable-bundle.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already know about the extensions which can do this, but I didn't find any extension free so cant use them. If you come up with another ideas please let me know. I am trying really hard for this, but still no luck.

Comment: I'm quite sure that developing this yourself will be more then the 199USD for this extension. The extension is fully open source, so no Ioncube and support is prompt and professional. It shouldn't be too hard to convince your client of this :).

Comment: well thanks for your suggestion even if I convince my client and he is ready to buy the extension its good, But how about if I want to do this for increasing my experience and knowledge. Atleast I should give a try for myself.