# buy a product from X category and buy a product from Y category and get 15% off on total price of two products , How to setup this?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

buy a product from X category and buy a product from Y category and get 15% off on the total price of two products, How to set up this?

15% should apply only to the total price of two products, not on the entire cart.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set my cart rules like below both condition and action.

Condition:

[image]

Action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Admin panel -> Marketing -> Cart Price Rules
```

or

```
Admin panel -> Marketing -> Catalog Price Rules
```

Here you can add new rules for your products and add conditions for discounts.

The following link (although being Magento 1.x) may get you on the right tracks:

[Create a Shopping Cart Rule - To offer 5% discount for two products or more](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3047/create-a-shopping-cart-rule-to-offer-5-discount-for-two-products-or-more)

Comment: This helped me. But I couldn't find a way to apply that discount only on the total of products from X and Y categories but not on the entire cart. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for my late reaction. Really busy atm. I'll look into it later this week, maybe I can find a solution for you. Bear with me.

Comment: No problem. I figured it. I really appreciate your passion. Thanks. I'm gonna add answer too. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: Np! Your answer will sure help a lot of other people!

Comment: Hi @bramulous, my solution is working perfectly when there is 1 product from X category and 1 product from Y category but the problem is when there are 2 products from X category and 1 product on Y category it is still calculating 15% discount on total 2*X+1*Y instead of only applying to 1*X+1*Y and bill the other 1*X fully. How to set this condition? Please help me when you have time. I have opened another thread for this question please reply there https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221586/give-discount-based-on-products-category-and-quantity-in-cart